# Yii2: Render data from a function called from javascript

Tags: javascript, function, controller, render, yii2

I have an ajax function, called from a button, that calls another function in my controller:

```
$('._save').on('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var data = {};
data.campos = window.campos;
data.secId = $('#Hidden1').val();

var success = function(data){
   console.log("Success!", data);
}
var error = function(data){
   console.log("Error!", data);
}

$.post('index.php?r=partidaasociada/get-linea',{ data : data });
```

This is the controller Function:

```
 public function actionGetLinea()
{               
    $model = new PartidaAsociada();
    $secId = $_POST['data']['secId'];

    for($i=0; $i<$cvectorpart;$i++)
    {
        $model->id_partidaasociada = null;
        $model->isNewRecord = true;
        $model->id_sector = $secId;
        $model->save();
    }

return $this->render('saveord', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);           

}
```

I need to render the data, to another view called "saveord", but it keeps doing nothing when i press the button (that calls the ajax function)

The code is saving the model the right way, i'd try 'renderPartial', 'renderAjax' and 'render' but nothing is working.

Comment: So from your code you seem to be expecting an ajax response, but don't seem to be doing anything with it. What are you expecting to happen? What response are you getting from the server?

Comment: I am expecting to the view to show up, i am just printing the data in the view. The response for the server is nothing, it just save the model and nothing more.